# Check when a value is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a process that runs when the command is issued in the discord bot, sometimes this process will fail and I need to know when it does. Every time after the command is issued and the process finishes it logs in console
`console.log ('Process done! All succeded: %s || All failed: %s'), allsucces, allfailed`

So every time **all succeded = 0** I want the bot to dm me in a discord message

Comment: I know how to send the DM message but I do not know how to make the check if the value is 0

Comment: `if (allSuccess == 0) { /*dm logic here?*/ }`

Comment: I'd suggest reading about the [Javascript Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics).

Comment: Hi @Ecstasyyy. Was the answers bellow helpful? Are you still facing issues with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply compare `allsucces` value to `0`

```js
if (allsucces === 0) {
  /* DM Logic */
}
```

These links might also provide you with some useful information regarding Javascript and how Comparison and logical Operators work:

[Javascript Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

[JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 values, use [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators).

Here's how they work:

```js
val == 0 // val has the value 0 but does not *need* to be the same type ("0" == 0 is true)
val === 0 // val is 0, both in value and type
val != 0 // opposite of "==" - val does not have the value 0
val !== 0 // opposite of "===" - val does not have the value 0, or is not the same type
val > 0 // val is more than 0
val < 0 // val is less than 0
val >= 0 // val is more than or equal to 0
val <= 0 // val is less than or equal to 0
```

See the difference between `===` and `==` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

To implement this in your code, use the `===` operator

```js
if (allsucces === 0) {
  // allsucces is equal to 0
}
```

And be sure `allsucces` is a number, not a string, otherwise the [strict equals operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) will make it return `false`!